# RAW, WAW, and WAR dependencies not detected

Tags: assembly, parallel-processing, dependencies, computer-science, cpu-registers

Consider the following assembly language program:

```
I1: Move R3, R7      /R3 ← (R7)/  
I2: Load R8, (R3)    /R8 ← Memory (R3)/
I3: Add R3, R3, 4    /R3 ← (R3) + 4/
I4: Load R9, (R3)    /R9 ← Memory (R3)/
I5: BLE R8, R9, L3   /Branch if (R9) > (R8)/
```

This program includes WAW,RAW,and WAR dependencies.Show these.

I have solved this for:

```
WAW: (I3, I1, r3) -> meaning I3 is dependant on I1 regarding r3

RAW: (I2, I1, r3); (I3, I1, r3); (I4, I3, r3); (I5, I2, r8); (I5, I4, R8)

WAR: (I3, I2, R3)
```

However I found a solution of the exercise on the internet and it stated that:

> •write-write: I1, I3
>   •read-write: I2, I3
>   •write-read: I1. I2

I really don't understand how they've come to that solution and why it seems to lack so many RAW dependencies. Which solution is right? Mine or theirs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after talking to a couple of guys who know about this kind of stuff, they've confirmed my solution is right and the one from the solutions book is wrong. Also, I've found another solution for the same problem on the net, here's the link: http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDI03/lecture-notes/seminar-2.frm.pdf

Hope it helps someone else out there who was stressing out like me! :D

Answer (score 0):

The hazards, in `register(intruction #, instruction #)` format, are:

- WAW: `R3(1,3)`
- WAR: `R3(2,3)`
- RAW: `R3(1,2), R3(1,3), R3(3,4), R8(2,5), R9(4,5)`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: This isn't actually code, it should be a bullet list.  It's just listing occurrences of each type of hazard in the form register(insn#, insn#).  Yes, it would be better to explain that, and probably have some text summary like "yes, you're right".  Also, we already know the same list posted in the question in a different format is right; the querent posted an answer saying so, with a supporting link.  (Although not to official errata for the book, unfortunately.)